# Creating a timer class in Java

Tags: java, timer

How would I create a timer `class` using Timer and TimerTask utils in Java. This way I can use my main class to create, start, track and delete timers as needed.

Below is my best example of the class I am looking for.

```
public class TimerClass {

  private Timer timer;
  private TimerTask timerTask;
  private int time;

 public TimerClass(){
    timer = new Timer();
    time = 0;
 }

 public void createTimer(){

 }

 public void runTimer(){

 }
 public int getTime(){
    return this.time;
 }
 public void deleteTimer(){

 }
 public void endTimer(){

 }
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't contain any problem statement. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the functions you want are `System.nanoTime();`, which returns the current time in nanoseconds. Simply record the difference between `System.nanoTime();`'s value when you start the timer, and it's value when you end the timer. This should give you the output you want.